# Raspberry PI wifi hotspot slow internet speed

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have created a Wifi hotspot using my Raspberry PI 3b+. The Wifi hotspot is working, the only problem is that the internet speed is slow. It takes forever to load something (30mbps). Maybe there is already a solution, but I can't find it. How do I make the internet speed of the hotspot faster?

Note: I am new to Raspberry PI.
Model: 3b+

List of specifications:

```
-Broadcom BCM2837B0, Cortex-A53 (ARMv8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.4GHz
-1GB LPDDR2 SDRAM
-2.4GHz and 5GHz IEEE 802.11.b/g/n/ac wireless LAN, Bluetooth 4.2, BLE Gigabit Ethernet over USB 2.0 (maximum throughput 300 Mbps)
-Extended 40-pin GPIO header
-Full-size HDMI
-4 USB 2.0 ports
-CSI camera port for connecting a Raspberry Pi camera
-DSI display port for connecting a Raspberry Pi touchscreen display
-4-pole stereo output and composite video port
-Micro SD port for loading your operating system and storing data
-5V/2.5A DC power input
-Power-over-Ethernet (PoE) support (requires separate PoE HAT)
```

Comment: which wireless band?

Comment: @JoeS dual-band wireless LAN

Comment: The radio can only work in one band concurrently. As such, the question remains: 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz?

Comment: @DanielB The purpose of the Raspberry PI is to serve as a Wifi Hotspot, I want it to be fast enough to connect to the internet and such things, so what would you recommend?

Comment: Spiff already covered all the details about band performance in his answer. It’s up to you to decide which band to use, based in the clients that will connect and whatnot. *I* would recommend getting a dual band (simultaneous) access point or router. It will provide acceptable range and throughput, both of which the Pi cannot provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 3b (without the '+') apparently has 2.4GHz-only, single spatial stream (1x1:1), b/g/n support. The fastest signaling rate that can get is 150Mbps when using 40MHz-wide channels, but 40MHz-wide channels are problematic in the crowded 2.4GHz band because it will overlap too many other APs, and not allow room for Bluetooth to work. So many devices don't use 40MHz-wide channels in 2.4GHz. So it's more reasonable to expect 20MHz-wide channels, limiting the signaling rate to 74.4Mbps. After Wi-Fi overhead, that amounts to 50Mbps or less of real throughput, even in ideal RF conditions.

If your client device is capable of 802.11n, then you might be able to improve speeds a bit by picking a cleaner channel and moving the client closer to the AP ("AP" is the proper name for what you're calling a "hotspot"). Also beware that 802.11n requires WMM (wireless QoS) and if you use wireless security/encryption, 802.11n requires WPA2 (AES-CCMP). Older original WPA (TKIP) and WEP are disallowed if you want to get 802.11n rates. But the fastest you can expect with the 3b's radio is 45 or *maybe* 50Mbps of throughput.

The Raspberry Pi 3b+ (with the '+') can do 802.11ac in 5GHz, presumably with 80MHz-wide channels. That should give you a max signaling rate of 433Mbps, for max throughputs in ideal conditions of 250-300Mbps, or maybe even slightly higher. This assumes your client supports 802.11ac and that you're connecting your 3b+ to a gigabit Ethernet LAN.

Comment: Okay thanks, but do you know any existing tutorial about upgrading the internet speed of the Raspberry PI, because I can't find any.